# jOOQ Dynamic Number of WITH Clauses

Tags: java, postgresql, common-table-expression, jooq

I am playing around with jOOQ and nesting queries. I have a JSON payload which may contain many subqueries. I want to treat these subqueries as a variable number of Common Table Expressions (i.e. CTE's in the WITH clause). Currently I have this working example, but it is static in terms of the number of CTE's it includes. How would I accomplish a variable number of CTE's within the WITH Clause?

```java
    /*
    +-----------------+
    |sum_of_everything|
    +-----------------+
    |              100|
    +-----------------+
     */
    Supplier<Stream<Map<String, Object>>> resultsWith =
        () ->
            dslContext
                .with("s1")
                .as(query)
                .select(sum(field("1", Integer.class)).as("sum_of_everything"))
                .from(table(name("s1")))
                .fetchStream()
                .map(Record::intoMap);
```

Ultimately I will need to deserialize the JSON payload to ensure that the CTE reference hierarchy works properly, and I will need to see if `jOOQ` supports referencing one CTE in another CTE before selecting the final result. I will need to accomplish something like this :

```java
    /*
    +-----------------+
    |sum_of_everything|
    +-----------------+
    |              100|
    +-----------------+
     */
    Supplier<Stream<Map<String, Object>>> resultsWith =
        () ->
            dslContext
                .with("s1").as(query1)
                .with("s2").as(query2) // should be able to reference "s1" i.e. query1
                ...
                .with("sNMinus1").as(queryNMinus1)
                .with("sN").as(queryN) // should be able to reference any upstream CTE
                .select(sum(field("1", Integer.class)).as("sum_of_everything"))
                .from(table(name("sN")))
                .fetchStream()
                .map(Record::intoMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`CommonTableExpression`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/CommonTableExpression.html) instance starting out from a [`Name`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Name.html), using [`Name.as(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Name.html#as(org.jooq.Select)) e.g.

```java
CommonTableExpression<?> s1 = name("s1").as(query1);
CommonTableExpression<?> s2 = name("s2").as(query2);

// And then (or, of course, use a Collection)
dslContext.with(s1, s2, ..., SN)
```